# Google Colab Pro - Slow

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colab Pro for some months now. Since 24 June the colab Pro is very slow.
Earlier an epoch was taking 37 minutes. Now it takes 2.5 hours to train(i have 20 epochs to train on) and after 24 hours, it just gets disconnected or terminated.

Data is not in any drive, I am copying it to content folder.

I am using "GPU" and High-RAM.
I am running attention learning for translating sentences from english-italian .

Please let me know what should I do be doing differently.

Thanks,
Naks

Comment: I am having the same problem. 2.5 hours/epoch running EfficientNetB0 + some layers. Have you found anything on how to speed it up?

Comment: No. I went for Colab pro